# Gridalicious library not loading grids in full screen width in Firefox

Tags: firefox

In my webpage, I am using [Grid-A-Licious](http://suprb.com/apps/gridalicious/) and in Firefox browser it is not loading properly. it is coming as a single grid in Firexox

See the images
[image: Firefox screen]

[image: Chrome screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can solve this by updating the CSS. Some how the with of the content class is getting 1/3 of the window in Firefox only.

We can comment the position absolute from the CSS and it will work fine.

Comment: You could give a code example. Please, also change "cess" to "css".

Comment: @ Jerone Thank you for the advise. The code are given below

.content-body {
    padding: 0 80px;
    max-width: 1920px;
    margin: 0px auto;
  /*  position: absolute; */
    height: 100%;
}